# Can a pillar page also be part of a content cluster?

Tags: seo, strategy

I am new to topic clusters, and I have a pillar page that can be a clusters to another pillar, *hubspot* [explained](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/what-is-a-pillar-page) it as every pillar linked to its clusters only.
[image]
However *overthinkgroup* [confirmed](https://overthinkgroup.com/pillar-page/) that you can.
[image]

So please can anyone who tried it confirms its result regarding to SEO.

Comment: As somebody that has done a lot of SEO, I've never used "pillar pages" or "content clusters" before.   They may work well, but they are certainly not the only linking structures that can produce good rankings.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. We don't know your content. Be that as it may, you are overthinking this. These pages describe organizing your site, however, much of this is what someone would do naturally. Just do what is right for you and your users. Use folders to organize content. Link between similar topics. Make it easier for users to find more content on your site. Write longer detailed pieces and simpler overviews for those who shy away from longer content. Keep it simple. The more you do, the more you will think of ideas to entice users to keep reading. Cheers!!